# DOCX merger/packager

Tags: merge

I have a few `DOCX` files and I’d like to merge them into packages as follows:

- Package 1: merge files `1a`, `2a`, `3a`, `4a`.
- Package 2: merge files `1b`, `2b`, `3b`, `4b`.
- Package 3: merge files `2a`, `3a`, `4a`, `5a`.
- Package 4: merge files `2b`, `3b`, `4b`, `5b`.

Then after modifying `2a` and `2b` I want to be able to simply run the merge again and get all four packages properly updated.

Is there a piece of software that might help me with this? I’m on Mac OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [docxcompose](https://pypi.org/project/docxcompose/) and a custom script.